# Before taking on a project, what to consider?

Tags: experience

If someone asks you to work for them, should you ask to see the picture first if it's available?

Answer (score 4):

I like to get as much information as I can about the project ahead of time:

- What's the scope of work
- How long is the project
- Do I find the project/material interesting
- How well have they planned for audio post (or haven't they)? What do they want the audio to do in their project?
- Do I have the time to provide what they're looking for?

I've mentioned in another [thread](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/quoting-for-post-sound-production) on this site that a project can described as "Good," "Fast," or "Cheap." It can be any two of those three ideas, but it will be the direct opposite of the third (i.e. for a project to be "Good" and "Fast," it will NOT be cheap..."Fast" and "Cheap" will not be "Good"). This is one of the biggest factors for me to be involved in a project. Personally, for freelance work, I will not allow myself to work on something that will not be good. [I have less say at my day job. ;)] My work reflects on me and my skills. If the circumstances do not offer me the opportunity to put forth my best effort, I will not take it. Which brings me to the next idea.

Do not oversell yourself...to the client, or yourself. If you have doubts about your ability to handle a particular assignment, make sure you evaluate them carefully. Know what you're getting yourself into. Know what your time is worth, and what the different tasks for a project requires. Completing any project is a system of controlled attrition; you won't be able to do everything perfectly. Make sure priorities are discussed and agreed upon (this goes back to the "scope" bullet-point), before you agree to start on the project.

And don't forget, you don't have to be the only audio person who works on a given project.

Comment: "Do I have the time to provide what they're looking for?"  -- That's probably the most important thing for freelancers.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully the picture isn't shot yet and they're taking you on in Pre-Production.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for information on the project. Is it a paid job? If so, do you have the time to work for free or not? If it is without pay, I would definetely ask to see the film in advance - if available. If it isn't shot yet, I would like to read a synopsis or treatment. If I know the director in advance, either in real life or by reputation, I could also make my decision based on that. If for instance I was asked to work on a film by David Fincher or Lars von Trier, I would probably say yes at once. If my schedule was free and the job is paid I would also say yes.

Comment: With regards to paid/unpaid, I'd like to link to this flowchart here... http://shouldiworkforfree.com/

Comment: glad i found that chart, my life is so much easier now

Comment: @Chris @Daan - i've only got one problem with that chart, it doesn't have a path for "i really like this idea/project." if i'm intrigued enough by something, and i have the availability, i might do it. ;)